# Not able to npm install "unlink 'H:\working_dir\node_modules\.mongoose.DELETE\lib\browser.js'"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Not able to run npm install. I wanted to delete node modules and then reinstall but I'm not able to delete because it shows this error:

```
npm ERR! path H:\Backend\notecrates_backend\node_modules\.mongoose.DELETE\lib\browser.js
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'H:\Backend\notecrates_backend\node_modules\.mongoose.DELETE\lib\browser.js'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hellstar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-23T13_51_38_148Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `npm config set unsafe-perm=true`

I hope you can fix that error by allowing unsafe perms

Comment: nope, after running the command I ran npm install still shows the same error